# Did Google Hangouts cease operating for free, as of late March 2017?

Tags: google-hangouts

My uncle could always dial any North American telephone number gratis with Google Hangouts, while he was in Canada, US, and England. But suddenly starting from late March 2017, every time that he tried, he could not and would encounter the following message:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  I currently use it and have just tested that it is still available.
**However** there may have been changes to the specific numbers or areas he is calling to or from that fall under the following exception (directly from the help page [Hangouts Help Page: Make a phone call with Hangouts](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3187125?hl=en&authuser=1&ref_topic=6386410))

> Almost all calls to the U.S. and Canada are free from all countries >where Hangouts calling is available. A few U.S. and Canadian >destinations will cost 1 cent per minute (USD), or the listed rate for >your local currency. Calls to destinations outside of the U.S. are at low >rates, but calling isn’t available to all locations.

Comment: Thanks. Did you test with a private #, or the one in my screenshot (for one of my uncle's favourite restaurants in Manhattan)? If so, then can you please test with another public number, to allow me to try to reproduce the result?